# Camerax ImageCapture passing to Chaquopy too slow

Tags: opencv, android-camerax, chaquopy

I made Camerax App with Chaquopy:

- ImageCapture use case capture the image(jpg)
- Convert it to Bitmap
- Convert Bitmap to string
- Pass string to Python
- Python OpenCV get image resolution and return it to Android (like a string)
- Show it on Textview

App is working,but problems are:

1. App is too slow: 15-20 secs (string conversion?)
2. It shows wrong resolution (resolution is set in ImageCapture config)

- How can I speed up my App??
- Is there another way to pass image to python besides base64 string??

Android CameraAtivity code:

'''

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PreviewView previewView;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.length);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);


        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    bindImageAnalysis(cameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }


    private void bindImageAnalysis(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

        Executor cameraexecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().setTargetResolution(new Size(1200, 1600)).build();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageCapture.takePicture(cameraexecutor, new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image){
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
                        byteBuffer.get(bytes);

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);


                        PyObject obj = pythonn(imgString);

                        textView.setText(obj.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }

        });


        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, imageCapture,
                preview);
    }

    private PyObject pythonn(String imgString) {
        if(!Python.isStarted())
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this ));
        Python py = Python.getInstance();

        final PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("shape");
        PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("main",imgString);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

'''

Python code;

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import base64

def main(imgString):

    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(imgString)
    np_data = np.fromstring(decoded_data,np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(np_data,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    if img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]:
        img = cv2.transpose(img)
    
    return str(str(img.shape[0]) + "_"  + str(img.shape[1]))
```

All Code is on Github:
https://github.com/kintipu/Camerax_ImageCapture_Chaquopy_OpenCV_ImageResolution/tree/master

UPDATED 29.03.2021.:
I will try with bytearray, like mhsmith suggested.
In meanwhile I tried another thing:

- Capture image and save it as jpg
- Then read image from python directly
  App works in emulator, but not on real mobile phone
  Android code:
  '''

  public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private PreviewView previewView;
  private ImageCapture imageCapture;
  private ListenableFuture cameraProviderFuture;
  private TextView textView;
  private Button button;
  private  Context context;

  ```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.length);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);


        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    bindImageAnalysis(cameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }


    private void bindImageAnalysis(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

        Executor cameraexecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().setTargetResolution(new Size(1200, 1600)).build();


        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                File file = new File(getBatchDirectoryName(), "photo"+ ".jpg");

                ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions outputFileOptions = new ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(file).build();
                imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, cameraexecutor, new ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback () {
                    @Override
                    public void onImageSaved(@NonNull ImageCapture.OutputFileResults outputFileResults) {
                        new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(CameraActivity.this, "Image Saved successfully" + file.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                PyObject obj = pythonn();
                                textView.setText(obj.toString());
                            }


                        });

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }
        });


        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, imageCapture,
                preview);
    }




    public String getBatchDirectoryName() {

        String app_folder_path = "";
        app_folder_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/images";
        File dir = new File(app_folder_path);
        if (!dir.exists() && !dir.mkdirs()) {

        }

        return app_folder_path;
    }





    private PyObject pythonn() {
        if(!Python.isStarted())
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this ));
        Python py = Python.getInstance();

        final PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("shape");
        PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("main");

        return obj;
    }
  ```

  }

'''

Python code:

'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from android.os import Environment


path = str(str(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()) + "/images" + "/photo.jpg")


def main():
    

    img = cv2.imread(path)
    
    return str(str(img.shape[0]) + "_"  + str(img.shape[1]))
```

'''

UPDATED 04.04.2021.:

I made it much quicker, by few modification:

- Passing image like bytearray to python (instead of string and base64 conversion) - on Malcom Smith suggestion
- Bitmap compress set to JPEG (instead of PNG)
- Python started on Create

Android code;
'''

```
public class CameraActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PreviewView previewView;
    private ImageCapture imageCapture;
    private ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider> cameraProviderFuture;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
        previewView = findViewById(R.id.previewView);
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.length);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        
        if(!Python.isStarted())
              Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this ));


        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get();
                    bindImageAnalysis(cameraProvider);
                } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    }


    private void bindImageAnalysis(@NonNull ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider) {

        Preview preview = new Preview.Builder().build();
        CameraSelector cameraSelector = new CameraSelector.Builder()
                .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK).build();
        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.createSurfaceProvider());

        Executor cameraexecutor = ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this);
        ImageCapture imageCapture = new ImageCapture.Builder().setTargetResolution(new Size(1200, 1600)).build();
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageCapture.takePicture(cameraexecutor, new ImageCapture.OnImageCapturedCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCaptureSuccess(@NonNull ImageProxy image){
                        ByteBuffer byteBuffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();

                        byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.capacity()];
                        byteBuffer.get(bytes);

                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();

//                        String length = String.valueOf((imgString.length()));
//                        textView.setText(length);

                        PyObject obj = pythonn(imageBytes);

                        textView.setText(obj.toString());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@NonNull ImageCaptureException error) {
                        error.printStackTrace();
                    }
                });
            }

        });


        cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner)this, cameraSelector, imageCapture,
                preview);
    }

    private PyObject pythonn(byte[] imageBytes) {

        Python py = Python.getInstance();

        final PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("shape");
        PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("main",imageBytes);
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Python:
'''

```
import cv2
import numpy as np



def main(imageBytes):
         np_data = np.asarray(imageBytes,np.uint8)
         img = cv2.imdecode(np_data,cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
         if img.shape[0] > img.shape[1]:
                img = cv2.transpose(img)

         img = cv2.resize(img, (1600, 1200))
    
         return str(str(img.shape[0]) + "_"  + str(img.shape[1]))
```

Updated github: https://github.com/kintipu/Camerax_ImageCapture_Chaquopy_OpenCV_ImageResolution/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use base64, you can just send the PNG-encoded `byte[]` array, and it will be received in Python as a bytes-like object. I'm not sure if this object will be accepted directly by `cv2.imdecode`, but it will definitely be accepted by `np.array` or `np.frombuffer`. (Passing binary data to `np.fromstring` is deprecated, as its [documentation page](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) explains.)

If you're not sure which line of code is causing the delay, you can add `Log` calls between the lines (or `print` calls in Python), and then check the timestamps in the [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html).

Comment: Thanks mhsmith, I will try it.